# CodeIgniter 3 fail to retain $_SESSION data, ci_session cookie generate each time refreshed

Tags: codeigniter-3

I can't get my session data return. I check with isset(), it always not set.
I try native session_start() without using session library it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue it is due to my version is 3.1.1 and I am using PHP 7.1 version. Upgrade to the latest version this bug has been fixed by CodeIgniter Team.

If you found that your session file every time refreshed will be generated a new one. Or you can check your ci_session cookie also keep refreshed every time. It is the sign.